# Como adicionar ♥♦♣♠ em um programa que roda no prompt de comando em C

Tags: c

To fazendo meu primeiro projeto de programação em C, e é um jogo de cartas. O problema é que eu não sei como adicionar o simbolo dos naipes para rodar no prompt. Eles não estão na tabela ascii, mas eu sei que tem como fazer. Podém me dar um norte? Obrigado

Comment: Este problema não é com C provavelmente, mas sim com o terminal que vai rodar, provavelmente depende da configuração da interface dele, até dá para usar o comando `system()`, mas em windows vai ser uma coisa e em outros emuladores de terminal vai ser outro comando dentro de `system()`, vai depender do sistema operacional que roda.

Comment: Algo assim, https://ideone.com/wmjMdj?

Comment: É só para windows o programa. Como posso fazer aparecer esses naipes no prompt do windows?

Comment: Caro user, como eu disse, vc pode até conseguir usando algum comando `system()`, mas é mais provavel que só será possivel configurando na propria interface do CMD, clicando com o direito do mouse no titulo da janela e depois propriedades, claro que acho que dê para fazer via system, mas estou inclinado a acreditar que algumas coisas em XP, 7, 8 e 10 possam variar.

Answer (score 0):

No meu ambiente (Ubuntu) rodou normalmente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("Naipes: ♠ ♣ ♥ ♦ ♡ ♢ ♤ ♧ \n");   
    return 0;
}

:~/Testes/C$ gcc -o naipes naipes.c
:~/Testes/C$ ./naipes
Naipes: ♠ ♣ ♥ ♦ ♡ ♢ ♤ ♧
```

Aqui também:
https://ideone.com/Aoq6Xv

Comment: Então, no windows não roda. esse é o resultado:Naipes: âT  âT£ âT¥ âT¦ âT¡ âT¢ âT¤ âT§

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53220783/what-locale-lc-ctype-is-used-for-windows-unicode-console-app

Comment: Caro Anonimo, no meu Ubuntu não roda, tem que configurar o terminal, logo a soução seria como configurar o terminal ou configurar o CMD (em Windows). Eu realmente não sei se wprintf+_setmode vai resolver, pq isso provavelmente implica "dependências" variando de sistema para sistema.